# cmake build command to show the debug info

Tags: cmake, ninja

i am trying to run cmake build with following configuration.

cmake config command:-

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCUTLASS_KTC_ARCHS=80 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -DCUTLASS_INSTALL_TESTS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=d:/test-worker/worker/tools-main/cutlass/install -DCMAKE_TEST_INSTALL_PREFIX=d:/test-worker/worker/tools-main/cutlass/install -Wno-dev d:/buildbot-worker/worker/build-tools-main/cutlass
```

cmake build command:-

```
cmake --build . --target install --verbose
```

Build fails as follows:-

```
[103/907] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --trace-expand -E vs_link_exe --intdir=examples\08_turing_tensorop_gemm\CMakeFiles\08_turing_tensorop_gemm.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1433~1.316\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe  examples\08_turing_tensorop_gemm\CMakeFiles\08_turing_tensorop_gemm.dir\turing_tensorop_gemm.cu.obj  /out:examples\08_turing_tensorop_gemm\08_turing_tensorop_gemm.exe /implib:examples\08_turing_tensorop_gemm\08_turing_tensorop_gemm.lib /pdb:examples\08_turing_tensorop_gemm\08_turing_tensorop_gemm.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL -LIBPATH:D:\buildbot-worker\worker\build-tools-main\cuda-image\lib64\stubs cudadevrt.lib  cudart_static.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib -LIBPATH:"D:/test-worker/worker/tools-main/cuda-image/lib/x64"  && cd ."
FAILED: examples/08_turing_tensorop_gemm/08_turing_tensorop_gemm.exe
```

Build fails with just single statement :- `FAILED: examples/08_turing_tensorop_gemm/08_turing_tensorop_gemm.exe`

But it's not showing any information why it failed. I try to run the build in verbose mode via `--verbose` and `-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON` to cmake build command. Am i doing something wrong?
Is there a way to get complete debug information? it would help me to triage the issue.Do i need to set anything for Ninja build system?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/900#issuecomment-132346047) it is suggested to run `ninja -v` for build the project (the option `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` is still needed when configure that project).

Comment: I have good experience on Gnumake, Where we used to have `-d` flag to show the complete dependency information which could help us to triage the issue. Similarly do we have any such mechanism in cmake/ninja?